# Samsung SyncMaster 740B DVI broken

Tags: display, vga, dvi

I have an old Samsung SyncMaster that I want to get going with my new computer (Geforce 750Ti graphics). 
The issue I have, is that the GeForce only has DVI and HDMI outputs, and my monitor doesn't seem to be playing nice with DVI.

When I click the 'source' button, the input switches between seemingly nothing and VGA. If I leave it on VGA for a few seconds, it displays 'check signal cable', and goes black (pixels black. Screen on). If I click 'source', it goes completely blank (pixels / backlight off).

If I click source again, it goes back to VGA like nothing ever happened.

Can anybody help? Spent some time on this issue myself and haven't found a solution.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Can I assume that you do have a signal on the DVI cable you are using? (it's plugged into a system outputting video)

Comment: @StevenDavison Yes. There his output. Mu other ancient monitor (BenQ FP7IG+S) is connected with a HDMI>DVI adapter, and works fine. I can plug DVI>DVI into it, and take the HDMI>DVI over to the syncMaster. Both cables have the same result, however the SyncMaster works fine on my Mac with a minidisplayport>VGA cable.

Comment: There are varients of DVI that i've personally never understood, some of which work digitally, and others are analogue. It's possible you are trying to convert between the two, without a processor to handle it... other than that, it does sound like the SyncMaster is faulty on DVI.